# How do I calculate the probable success rate of a game of chance?

Tags: probability

In this game I'm programming the player has to test a skill number plus a random number between 1 and 12 to see if it's greater or equal to a difficulty number. What I want to do is calculate the success rate of that test as a percentage. So if the skill test is n + random(12) => x, how do I calculate the probable rate of success as a percentage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the random to be at least $x-n$.  Each count contributes $\frac {100}{12}=8\frac 13 \%$.  So the success rate is $(13+n-x)8\frac 13\%$.  The $12$ becomes $13$ because the player wins ties.

Comment: @GerhardBahnsen:  Then you need to truncate into the range $0\$-100\%$

Comment: Hi. How would I enter this expression on a scientific calculator. I seem to be entering it in all wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @GerhardBahnsen:  I had a typo in the final expression, with $n,x$ reversed.  See if that helps.